# Removing characters in specific context with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove characters that appear in certain context and I can't figure out the way to do it. Let's say I want to remove every occurence of x before a vowel. Is it something like: s/x[aeiou]/   and then what? How to replace the x with nothing and keep the match that comes after it?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html):

```
s/x([aeiou])/$1/g
```

Details:

- `x([aeiou])` - matches an `x` and captures the next vowel
- `$1` is a backreference that holds the vowel, and thus the vowel is restored.

The `/g` is here to replace all matches.